# Reading text file to jQuery returns `object Object`, not text/string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to read a one line `.txt` file to a variable.  I later want to show that variable in the webpage.

My folder structure:

```
NewsAlerts
    index.html
    assets
        searchterms.txt
        js
            newsalerts.js [THIS is the .js that runs the code below]
        css
            style.css
```

My `searchterms.txt` is solely comprised of:

```
Chicago AND Illinois OR (Summer AND Winter)
```

so I am simply expecting my javascript variable to hold that string.

Code:

```
var search_terms = $(".text").load("assets/searchterms.txt");

$("#terms_submission").on("click", function(){
    $("#terms_list").add("<span>" + search_terms);
    alert(search_terms.valueOf());
});
```

jQuery does seem to be loading something, if I add `alert(search_terms)`, I get `[object Object]`.  But doing `search_terms.text()` returns `""` so maybe it's correctly creating an Object variable ...but with nothing in it.

Comment: don't use `.load` - use `$.get`

Comment: Docs never say .load() will assign loaded value to a variable. "When a successful response is detected, .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data"

Comment: If you're not sure what an object looks like use `console.dir(object)` instead of `alert(object)`.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Doing `var search_terms = $(".text").get("assets/searchterms.txt");` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Also just trying `var search_terms = $.get("assets/searchterms.txt")` returns `> Object // undefined` where the `//` means new line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have to do with the cross origin requests.  The way to solve that, at least locally, is to start a local server from the `News Alerts` folder.

Instructions for Windows:

1. Open the command prompt and change the directory to the top folder of the project.
2. Start a local server with `python -m http.server` [note this is Python 3]
3. Navigate to `http://localhost:8000/`
4. The script will now run.

FWIW the final script I'm using is:

```
$.get(TXT, function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("new_search_terms").attr("placeholder", data);
});
```